# Eclipse (Springsource tool suite) menu items on UHD/4k screen

Tags: eclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I just installed STS/Eclipse on a new laptop with UHD display. STS/Eclipse starts with menu icons in native resolution which makes them too small and unusable.

Is there any way to zoom/scale the menu/icon rendering in STS/Eclipse?

Thank you

Comment: What OS? Fiddling with monitor resolutions is probably a OS-specific thing. E.g. Mac OS retina Eclipse works pretty well out of the box. So what OS are you on?

Comment: @Kris Windows 10 - vanilla installation on Dell XPS 15. STS 3.7.3 based on Eclipse 4.6. Interestingly enough, standalone Eclipse neon (4.6) displays the icons correctly.

Comment: I entered the issue here https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4381

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is as well as the solution (enabling HiDPI support) is discussed here https://jaxenter.com/netbeans/hidpi-with-eclipse-and-netbeans